# Move an object in OpenGL ES for iOS?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, touch

I want to move an object to a specific point on the screen. (Specifically, wherever the user touches, barring any collisions that may interfere.) What OpenGL ES call am I supposed to use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a equivalent method of gluUnProject, which transforms from screen coordinates to world coordinates. There is one implementation specific to iPhone [here](http://www.flexicoder.com/blog/index.php/2009/11/iphone-gluproject-and-gluunproject/).

Basically, it uses the modelview and projection matrices to do the transformation.